# How to convert an iife old ways function to an arrow function in a single line

Tags: javascript, iife

how would you convert:

```
(function(age) {return `your ${age}`;
})(10);
```

to an arrow function? I tried but doesnt work:

```
(const years = (age) => `your ${age}`)(10);
```

Why does not work and if it is because of const?

And then another example, if I make:

```
const marco= { name: 'marco ccc',
  say hi: function () {
  return 'something';
  }
}
```

how would I convert sayHi into an arrow function?

Comment: Why try to name the arrow function? You don't do it in the iife version.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Especially in the case of the object method? This doesn't really make sense.

Comment: console.log(((age) => your age is ${age}) (10));

Comment: i am trying to understand how to convert correctly an Invoked Function Expression with arrow function and then again convert a function on an object into an arrow function. To learn and test, I know does not make sense

Comment: const marco = { sayHi: () => 'something', name: 'marco' };

Comment: Thanks a lot, Daniel, so const years = ((age) => your ${age})(10);
is a shorter version than something like:
const years = (age) => your ${age};
const whatever = years(10);
console.log(whatever)?

am I understanding right?

Comment: another thing why const marco = { sayHi: () => 'something'}
does not have a const like  const marco = { sayHi: const test = () => {'something'}} ? why did you omit const ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expressions get assigned to variables. Arrow functions are generally composed of 2 parts: the variable it's assigned to, and the body, eg:

```
const foo = () => { ... }
// ^ variable
            ^^^^ function body
```

Initialization of variables can only be done as a *statement*, on a standalone line; the `const` can't be inside parentheses. You just need to separate out the variable the return value is being assigned to from (the function body *and* the call of the function):

```js
const years = ((age) => `your ${age}`)(10);
//             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//             this is the function body
//             that needs to be invoked immediately
//                                     ^^ with the (10)
//    ^^^^^    with the result assigned to `years`
console.log(years);
```

In an object, just replace `function()` with `() =>` (and note that `say hi` isn't a valid object property in an object literal - either surround it in quotes, or use a single word instead):

```js
const marco = {
  name: 'marco ccc',
  sayHi: () => {
    return 'something';
  }
};

console.log(marco.sayHi());
```

Comment: But in my case, I was wondering how my Immediately Invoked Function Expression would be converted with the arrow function.

Another example, that makes me wonder is if I have something like:

const marco= {
     name: 'marco ccc'
     say hi: function () { return 'something'}
}


In a way that i can call marco.sayHi();  How can I make sayHi() as arrow function?

Comment: The `(age) => \`your ${age}\`` *is* an arrow function. Press "Run code snippet" to see it working. But the `const marco= { name: 'marco ccc' say hi: function () {} }` from your comment is not valid syntax. Did you mean `const marco= { name: 'marco ccc', sayHi: function () {} }`? Then use `const marco= { name: 'marco ccc', sayHi: () => {} }`

Comment: Sorry my bad, but to make immediately invoked 
(age) => `your ${age}`
can be something like
((age) => `your ${age}` )(10); 
and if yes why const is not used?

Comment: If you want to use the result of the invocation, no matter whether you're using an arrow function or a `function`, you need to assign it to a variable (or do something else with it). Eg `const years = (function(age) {return \`your ${age}\`;})(10);` is equivalent to `const years = ((age) => \`your ${age}\`)(10);`.

Comment: but what is the point of the IIFE then? whether i choose:
console.log(((age) => your age is ${age}) (10)); 

or
 const years = ((age) => `your ${age}`)(10);

Comment: If you only need to do *one thing* with the resulting expression, then you don't need to assign it to a variable. If all you want to do is log it, then sure, you can do that.

Comment: I was trying to understand if:

const years = ((age) => your ${age})(10); is a shorter version than something like: const years = (age) => your ${age}; const whatever = years(10); console.log(whatever)? am I understanding right?

Comment: Yes, that's right, and all of those are also equivalent to `console.log((function(age) { return 'your ' + age; })(10));`

Comment: Ok now makes sense, thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I did it:) just last question but why you don't declare inside sayHi: const something = () => ({'hello'}); ?

Comment: If you already have the `sayHi` function, why wrap it in another function with `something`? Easier to define stuff outright when possible, usually

Answer (score 2):

I do this often when creating async closures so I can use await inside a non-async function body. It looks like this:

```
(async (arg1,arg2) => {
  console.log(arg1,arg2); // logs a,b
})('a','b');
```

It saves me from creating a `const` and then calling it, like this:

```
const outerFunc = () => {

   // ... some code

   const innerFunc = async () => {
      // I can use await in here
   };
   innerFunc();
}
```

and instead I do this:

```
const outerFunc = () => {

   // ... some code

   (async () => {
      // I can use await in here
   })();
}
```

To juse create the closure, leave off the async part

```
((...args) => console.log(...args))('a','b');
```

EDIT: If you look closely at the above, you'll see it actually shortens to

```
(console.log)('a','b')
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically  I wanted to convert these two functions (old version):

```
(function(age) {return `your ${age}`;
})(10);
```

and

```
const marco= { name: 'marco ccc',
  say hi: function () {
  return 'something';
  }
}

console.log(marco.sayHi());
```

Which converted are respectively:

```
((age) => your age is ${age})(10);
```

and

```
const marco= { name: 'marco ccc', sayHi: () => {} }
```

But in addition, I was trying to understand the benefit of IIFE, for instance:

```
const years = ((age) => your ${age})(10);
```

is a shorter version than something like:

```
const years = (age) => your ${age}; 
const whatever = years(10); 
console.log(whatever);
```

Comment: There are two benefits of iife, if you aren't using it to create an async closure inside a non-async function, then there's only one - to create a closure. And honestly, the benefits of creating a closure using an iife in modern JavaScript are largely (not entirely, but largely) 
 mitigated by [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let), although you might see iife's used for stylistic reasons, Don't create an iife unless you are sure you need one. If you aren't sure if you need one, you don't need one.